# shell script set the default numbers as double digit zero as prefix

Tags: shell-script, shell, numeric-data

In a shell script, I'm processing, some addition process will print an output. If it is a single-digit one, then it has to add zero as a prefix.

Here is my current script:

```
c_year=2020
for i in {01..11}
        do  
            n_year=2020
            echo 'Next Year:'$n_year
            if [[ $i == 11 ]]
            then n_month=12
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            else 
            n_month=$(($i + 1))
            echo 'Next Month:'$n_month
            fi
            echo $date" : Processing data '$c_year-$i-01 00:00:00' and '$n_year-$n_month-01 00:00:00'"
        done
```

The `i` value is in doule digit, but the `n_month` is still printing single digit. How do I set default shell output should return as double digit?

Or any alternate way to solve this?

Comment: Could you clarify what is special about 11? Wouldn't 10 be in the same situation, being a double digit? If I understand correctly.

Comment: Thats for my use case, for year 2020, I have to print up to 11 if not 2020 then print up to 12. I cut the if part only here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a possibility, simplifying:

```
for i in {1..11}; do  
    n_month=$(($i + 1))
    [[ $n_month =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] && n_month="0$n_month"
    echo "$n_month"
done

Output

02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not use leading zeros in variables where you want to store decimal values because in various contexts a number with leading zero is interpreted as *octal*. Arithmetic expansion is one of these contexts. The following code fails:

```bsh
i1=09
i2=$((i1+1))
```

while this one works:

```bsh
i1=9
i2=$((i1+1))
```

Add leading zeros only when printing the results. Do this by using `printf` with a proper format. Example:

```bsh
i1=9
i2=$((i1+1))
year1=2020
year2=2020

printf "Processing data '%04d-%02d-01 00:00:00' and '%04d-%02d-01 00:00:00'\n" "$year1" "$i1" "$year2" "$i2"
```

---

Note when `printf` expects a number, it interprets a string with leading zero as octal number. So this is another context where you need to be careful. Example:

```bsh
$ printf '%02d\n' 9
09
$ printf '%02d\n' 09
printf: '09': value not completely converted
00
$ printf '%02d\n' 012
10
```

This means while `printf %02d` can be a solution when you avoid leading zeros, it may be a bug when you don't.